# Wordpress; Menus/Page Structure; Multiple Children

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site that is going to have multiple children. Along the lines of:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1
  - Child 2

    - Grand Child 1
    - Grand Child 2
  - Child 3
- Parent 2

  - Child 1
  - Child 2

    - Grand Child 1
    - Grand Child 2
  - Child 3

Is there a really easy way to generate this in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In page attributes, you can do this by default.